# Conversion ECEF XYZ to LLH (LAT/LONG/HEIGHT) and translation back - not accurate / possible error in IronPython script

Tags: latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, elevation, xyz

I've modeled a *3D earth* with gridpoints, as below:

[image: Earth]

The points are represented in 3D space as **XYZ** coordinates.
I then convert **XYZ** to **Lat/Long/Height**(elevation) based on the script I took from here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mozkan/nz1otcaq/)

For some reason I got really strange results when trying to find **XYZ** of **LLH** not from my set, so I tried to verify the initial script by converting **XYZ** to **LLH** and then **the same** **LLH** back to **XYZ** to see if I get the same coordinate.

Instead, the resulting coordinate is some **XYZ** on earth, unrelated to the original **XYZ** position.

**XYZ to LLH script**:
Source: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mozkan/nz1otcaq/)

```
def xyzllh(x,y,z):
    """        xyz vector  to  lat,lon,height
         output:
    
              llhvec[3] with components
    
              flat      geodetic latitude in deg
              flon      longitude in deg
              altkm     altitude in km
    """
    dtr =  math.pi/180.0
    rrnrm = [0.0] * 3
    llhvec = [0.0] * 3
    
    geodGBL()
    
    esq = EARTH_Esq

    rp = math.sqrt( x*x + y*y + z*z )
    flatgc = math.asin( z / rp )/dtr
    testval= abs(x) + abs(y)
    
    if ( testval < 1.0e-10):
        flon = 0.0
    else:
        flon = math.atan2( y,x )/dtr 
    if (flon < 0.0 ):
        flon = flon + 360.0
    
    p = math.sqrt( x*x + y*y )
    
    # on pole special case
    
    if ( p < 1.0e-10 ):
        flat = 90.0
        if ( z < 0.0 ):
            flat = -90.0
        altkm = rp - rearth(flat)
        llhvec[0]  = flat
        llhvec[1]  = flon
        llhvec[2]  = altkm
        return  llhvec

    # first iteration, use flatgc to get altitude 
    # and alt needed to convert gc to gd lat.
    
    rnow = rearth(flatgc)
    altkm = rp - rnow
    flat = gc2gd(flatgc,altkm)
    
    rrnrm = radcur(flat)
    rn = rrnrm[1]
    
    for x in range(5):
        slat = math.sin(dtr*flat)
        tangd = ( z + rn*esq*slat ) / p
        flatn = math.atan(tangd)/dtr
    
        dlat = flatn - flat
        flat = flatn
        clat = math.cos( dtr*flat )
    
        rrnrm = radcur(flat)
        rn = rrnrm[1]
    
        altkm = (p/clat) - rn
    
        if ( abs(dlat) < 1.0e-12 ):
            break

    llhvec[0]  = flat
    llhvec[1]  = flon
    llhvec[2]  = altkm
    return llhvec 
# globals
EARTH_A = 0
EARTH_B = 0
EARTH_F = 0
EARTH_Ecc = 0
EARTH_Esq = 0

# starting function do_llhxyz()
CallCount = 0
llh  = [0.0] * 3
dtr = math.pi/180

CallCount = CallCount + 1

sans = " \n"

llh = xyzllh(x,y,z)

latitude = llh[0]
longitude= llh[1]
hkm = llh[2]
height = 1000.0 * hkm

latitude = fformat(latitude,5)
longitude = fformat(longitude,5)
height = fformat(height,1)

sans = sans +"Latitude,Longitude, Height (ellipsoidal) from ECEF\n"
sans = sans + "\n"
sans = sans +"Latitude  : " + str(latitude)  + "   deg N\n"
sans = sans +"Longitude : " + str(longitude - 180) + "   deg E\n"
sans = sans +"Height    : " + str(height)    + "   m\n"

lats = []
longs = []
heights = []
lats.append(str(latitude))
longs.append(str(longitude - 180))
heights.append(str(height))
```

**And this is the LLH to XYZ script:**
Source: [www.mathworks.com](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7942-covert-lat-lon-alt-to-ecef-cartesian)

```
a = 6378137
t = 8.1819190842622e-2

# (prime vertical radius of curvature)
N = a / math.sqrt(1 - (t*t) * (math.sin(lat)*math.sin(lat)))

x = []
y = []
z = []

# results:
x.append( ((N+height) * math.cos(lat) * math.cos(long))/1000 )
y.append( ((N+height) * math.cos(lat) * math.sin(long))/1000 )
z.append( (((1-t*t) * N + height) * math.sin(lat))/1000 )
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any `geodGBL()` function in your JSFiddle code. And it's not neither defined in your question  XYZ to LLH script. Looks like you are not considering Earth's shape (a,e) in your code.

Comment: @LuisTavares as I said in the post, I didn't copy the full JSFiddle. If you go there and go to Resources you'll find the .js file with all the relevant functions. https://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/coord/geodesy.js

Comment: The code from NPS I can assure it's correct (I've used it long time ago). What you are doing with it nobody is going to debug it for you.